# Merge Git branches while maintaining individual branch layout

Tags: git, command-line, git-branch

I'm trying to follow the now famous [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) model of development, but I'm having some difficulty understanding how to perform some operations from the command-line. If I run `git merge develop` from the master branch, the history of the develop branch is moved to the master branch. EX:

Here's how my repo looks before the merge:

```
              F--G--H--I Develop
             /
A--B--C--D--E Master
```

This is what it looks like after the merge:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I Master
```

This is what I want it to look like after the merge:

```
              F--G--H--I Develop
             /          \
A--B--C--D--E------------J Master
```

I can only get the desired result if I use the 'merge request' feature of my git web interface ([gitlab](https://gitlab.com)). I know that there has to be a way to do this with vanilla git, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `--no-ff` flag on `git merge`. `ff` stands for fast-forward; since Master hasn't advanced since Develop, `git` can do the merge with a guarantee that there will be no merge conflicts to resolve. `git` calls this type of merge a fast-forward merge. The `--no-ff` flag forces `git` to do a non-fast-forward merge, which means that it will make an explicit merge commit (`J` in your diagram).

In sum:

```
git merge --no-ff develop
```

which is what gitlab does when you merge through the web interface.